# Field structure of vectors in $\mathbb{R}^3$

Tags: field-theory, vector-spaces

Probably a trivial question: By representing vectors in $\mathbb{R}^2$ as complex numbers we can define multiplication of vectors so that $\mathbb{R}^2$ has a field structure. Can this be extended to $\mathbb{R}^3$ or in general to $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: Not in a way that respects the vector space structure over the reals.

Comment: Here's what one teacher on the subject said to my class when the subject came up:

"No. In general, you can try to represent higher and higher powers of $\mathbb{R}$ with multiplication but each time you lose some important property. When you go from reals to complex you lose ordering. When you go from complex to quaternions, you lose commutativity."

Comment: The only finite-dimensional real division algebras have dimension 1, 2, 4 or 8. The only finite-dimensional associative and commutative real division algebras are $\bf R$ or $\bf C$. But we're still free to put all sorts of algebraic structure (compatible with the underlying vector space structure) on ${\bf R}^n$, as long as we're willing to lose some things.

Comment: See this page: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_theorem_(real_division_algebras)

Comment: See also the Cayley-Dickson construction: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley-Dickson_construction